# Distributed Scalable Decision Trees

Tags: classification, bigdata, decision-trees

Are there any good sources that explain how decision trees can be implemented in a scalable way on a distributed computing system.  Where in a given source is this explained?

Answer (score 3):

[Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/) [can do it](http://spark-summit.org/2014/talk/scalable-distributed-decision-trees-in-spark-mllib), using the new [MLLib](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/mllib-decision-tree.html) library. [Here's a presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rRrcPXHu98), and [here are some benchmarks](http://databricks.com/blog/2014/09/29/scalable-decision-trees-in-mllib.html). Bindings are available for python, scala, and java.

Answer (score 2):

You should read the paper from Google on PLANET, which was their distributed MapReduce-based implementation of random decision forests: http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/36296.pdf

You may or may not like the architecture but there are a number of interesting ideas about scaling up here.